# plotly linetype poperty setting in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to set the line type("solid", "dash", "dot" etc) for multiple lines in plotly. I have a column(factor variable) in my data frame which specifies the type of line.

Below is the sample code I am working with.

```
mydf <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y1 = c(11:20), y2 = c(21:30))
mydf1 <- gather(mydf,'var', 'val', -x)
mydf1$lt <- factor(c(rep("solid",10),rep("dot",10)))
pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(nlevels(mydf1$lt),"Set1")
p <-plot_ly(mydf1, x = x, y = val, type = 'line', color = var,colors = pal,line = list(width = 3, dash = lt))
p<- layout(p,title = "Hello", annotations = list(x = mydf1$x, y = mydf1$var))

p
```

mydf1$lt specifies the required line type.
For the above example, y1 must be solid line and y2 must be dotted line.

[image]

I can solve the issue by individually adding lines using add_trace(). I am looking for a more concised, elegant way of doing the same. Below is one possible solution.

```
p1 <- plot_ly(mydf)
p1 <- add_trace(p1, x = x, y = y1, line = list(dash = "dash"))
p1 <- add_trace(p1, x = x, y = y2, line = list(dash = "solid"))
p1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the above example, y1 must be solid line and y2 must be dotted
>   line.

You could do

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)
mydf <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y1 = c(11:20), y2 = c(21:30))
mydf1 <- gather(mydf,'var', 'val', -x)
mydf1$lt <- factor(c(rep("solid",10),rep("dot",10)))
pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(nlevels(mydf1$lt),"Set1")
p <-plot_ly(
  transform(mydf1, lt=c(solid="solid", dot="3")[lt]), 
  x = x, 
  y = val, 
  type = 'line', 
  color = var,
  colors = pal,
  line = list(dash = lt)
)
p <- layout(
  p,
  title = "Hello", 
  annotations = list(x = mydf1$x, y = mydf1$var)
)
p
```

Or `c(solid="3", dot="solid")[lt]` if you want it the other way around.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Could you explain what the "3" mean for "dot". What kind of enumeration/transformation happens between linetype and the corresponding number?

Comment: `3` is the dot spacing/width of dashed lines. (I got that from the online manual.)  `c(solid="solid", dot="3")[lt]` maps your factor level `dot` to the value `3`.

Comment: not working for me ? `Error in plot_ly(transform(data, lt = c(solid = "solid", dot = "3")[lt]),  : 
  object 'lt' not found`